# Align right side of assignment with Tabular.vim

Tags: regex, vim, tabular

Using the vim tabular plugin, I'm trying to achieve the following:

Convert from this:

```
var longString = 'Hello, ' +
    'this ' +
    'is ' +
    'a long' +
    'string';
```

to this:

```
var longString = 'Hello, ' +
                 'this ' +
                 'is ' +
                 'a long' +
                 'string';
```

So far, the closest I've gotten is the following Tabularize command:

```
:'<,'>Tabularize /^\(.\+=\)\?\s
```

However this seems to give me an extra space:

```
var longString =  'Hello, ' +
                  'this ' +
                  'is ' +
                  'a long' +
                  'string';
```

Why is the above expression adding the extra space, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tabular uses `/^\(.\+=\)\?\s` as the field delimiter. To make it look nice Tabular puts a space after it since it assumes that the field delimiter doesn't end in a space.

If you add the `l0` flag after the delimiter you will remove the extra space to the left of the next field.

```
:Tabularize /^\(.\+=\)\?\s/l0
```

From the doc

> A format specifier is either l, r, or c, followed by one or more
>   digits.  If the letter is l, the field will be left aligned, similarly
>   for r and right aligning and c and center aligning.  The number
>   following the letter is the number of spaces padding to insert before
>   the start of the next field.

The default format flags are found in `g:tabular_default_format` which is set to `l1`.

Answer (score 2):

Mark the start of the match via `\zs` and use `.*` to consume the rest of the line

```
:Tabularize /^\(.\+=\)\?\s\+\zs.*
```

Comment: Technically that works, however every consecutive run adds another space. Is there some way to make the command idempotent?

Comment: You can add the `l0` flag like @FDinoff says